# Can't open Spyder from Mac

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I couldn't open SPYDER after I have downloaded Anaconda. The Anaconda navigator wouldn't open too. Is there an alternative solution like opening Spyder from the command line?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What exactly are you trying? You've already tried the `spyder` command in the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acording the [documentation](https://conda.io/docs/faq.html#creating-new-environments) (I don't know your python version):

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.4 anaconda
```

This will create virtual environment to `virtualenv`.
To activate it :

```
source venv/bin/activatec:\anaconda2 directory)
```

To check the current environment has been changed:

```
conda info -e
```

And now to run Spyder with Python 3.4 just type:

```
spyder
```

Comment: Why are you suggesting the OP create a new conda environment? Spyder should be in the root environment by default.

Comment: I am using python 3.6. Thank you so much, it works for me :)

Comment: @RichieSingh you are welcome, don't forget to accept the answer with (✓), and vote, now you can congrats :)}